# Is there a way to declare props as optional in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have created some components which take an optional prop like `hide={true}`. My problem is that these annoying error messages always flood my console when I don't pass that prop:

```
<MyComponent> was created without expected prop 'hide'
```

Is there some way to declare the props as optional?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just give them a default value.

**MyComponent.svelte**

```html
<script>
  export let i = 123 // Default value is now 123
</script>

<!-- Output is "i = 123" -->
<p>i = {i}</p>
```

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import MyComponent from './MyComponent.svelte'
</script>

<!-- No error here! -->
<MyComponent/>
```

So, in your case you would change `export let hide` to `export let hide = false`.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought of that workaround. Seems to be the only way currently.

Comment: I don't see that as a workaround. See, you have a component that expects a property (and does not have a default) and you don't pass one. Then you have a good chance that the app will not work correctly. Each component should define defaults for the properties and work even if none as passed. If you can't assign default values to properties, then check those error messages for missing props or throw an error is component is mounted without a required prop.

Comment: Correct — it's not a workaround, it's *how it's designed to work*

Comment: Ok, if that was the intention then I will declare default props in the future. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 8):

In some cases you don't want a default value so it's better to make the default `null`.

#### MyComponent.svelte

```html
<script>
  export let myProp = null // Default value is null
</script>

<div class:has-some-prop={myProp}>
{#if myProp }
Has Prop: {myProp}
{:else}
No Prop
{/if}
</div>
```

#### App.svelte

```html
<MyComponent/>
<MyComponent myProp='yep'/>
```

#### Result

```html
<div>No Prop</div>

<div class:has-some-prop>
Has Prop<span>yep</span>
</div>
```

### Update for Svelte 5 (3/7/24)

In Svelte 5 you [declare your props with Runes](https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/docs/runes#$props) like this:

```js
let {hide} = $props(); // hide is undefined
```

**For defaults:**

```js
let {hide=true} = $props();
```

**With types you could do something like this:**

```
interface ComponentProps {
  optional?: boolean;
  optionalWithDefault?: boolean;
  required: boolean;
}
let {optional, optionalWithDefault = true, required} = $props<ComponentProps>();
```