# How define an optional prop in svelte with typescript?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I want to declare an optional prop in svelte with typescript, but I get the following error: "Declaration or statement expected". How can I declare the prop correctly?

My Type

```
export enum MyVariants {
  one = 'one',
  two = 'two'
}
```

Svelte component

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let variant?: MyVariants;
</script>
```

Error:

```
   ts Declaration or statement expected
```

Comment: At least closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405066/is-there-a-way-to-declare-props-as-optional-in-svelte

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Caveat: I haven't used Svelte (yet!)

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62405171/157247), the way you make a prop optional in Svelte is to give it a default value (an initializer on the declaration).

So in your case, you'd define explicitly that it could be `undefined` and assign it a default value of `undefined`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let variant: MyVariants | undefined = undefined;
</script>
```

---

If you're going to do this a lot, you might want a reusable type like this which perhaps provides some semantic value:

```typescript
type Optional<T> = T | undefined;
```

Giving you:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let variant: Optional<MyVariants> = undefined;
</script>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQJwUwVwM4EMBGAbGoAuBPADjAFwBQuBoA8nlgJYD2AdkmgDwAqAfKALyhugAfUHAYATGADMaDGKIDcxYiFABlLHAkTQCAgGMaU3djrYAFpl10AtnkYwGWEjAAetqFlD24V0AFkcAGpIUDRIDgigAN7EoKB2PKAA5HaJADQx2ADuJryJWNmJxAC+isoAkgxmFta2Mg6JEQi6IdQkGB4AbsGhDoSU1PRMrP5BIWFYCFy8IuJSMvLEQA)

And if you want to, you can write `undefined` as `void 0`. (I don't, but I'm often tempted.) That would give you:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let variant: Optional<MyVariants> = void 0;
</script>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQJwUwVwM4EMBGAbGoAuBPADjAFwBQuBoA8nlgJYD2AdkmgDwAqAfKALyhugAfUHAYATGADMaDGKIDcxYiFABlLHAkTQCAgGMaU3djrYAFpl10AtnkYwGWEjAAetqFlD24V0AFkcAGpIUDRIDgigAN7EoKB2PKAA5HaJADQx2ADuJryJWNmJxAC+isoAkgxmFta2Mg6JEQi6IdQkGB4AbsGhDoSU1PRMrP5BIWFYCFy8HXQ0oqAADApAA)

Or you could have a do-nothing utility function providing both the type and the `undefined` value:

```typescript
function optional<T>(): T | undefined {
  return undefined;
}
```

That would give you:

```html
<script>
let variant = optional<MyVariants>();
</script>
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQJwUwVwM4EMBGAbGo4BcCWbdsBPUAMzgDsBjPAewoC4Aoc6ui0WgB3aTQB4AKgD4AFAEoGoQaAA+WCgBMYpXBRiLQAbyahoMbHCgdKy1esUBuJgF8mTEKADKh0qVAIuMKrlVVQ2LQBABaYVLQAtlz0MBTYzDAAHtFQ2KCxcBGgALJEAGpIULhIcQjaupzqoAC8oADkMXUANBXYAO5BtXXttHW29o4AkhzYoaDhUTFxdWUIVEU8zBhpAG6FxXE1nDy49Hz8uQVFJdgIYuLWQA)

Comment: Ah cool it works, but not very efficient, that I always have to write "undefined"

Comment: @vuvu - Yeah. :-| There are things you can do to make it a bit shorter (give yourself a reusable `Optional` type and then [`let variant: Optional<MyVariants> = void 0;`](https://tsplay.dev/NrQ0Dw)), but...

Comment: @vuvu - I've added a couple of thoughts to the answer. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

It is an optional property if you give it a default value.

```html
export let variant: MyVariants | undefined = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

That also works fine:

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let item: MyVariant;
</script>
```

I'm using TypeScript 5.1.3 and Svelte 4.2.1

Comment: It doesn't seem right. Your IDE is probably misconfigured and not showing typescript errors properly. If you're using vite for development, then you should note that it doesn't perform any type checking (leaving this job to your IDE). More info here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#typescript